# What type of React.Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a search function; it receives react.hooks as the first argument and I do not know which type is in X.It seems to be equal Dispatch.if another way to give type?
[Codesandbox Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jk016vkl3)

```
import React, { FC, Fragment, Dispatch,SetStateAction } from 'react'

const SearchText:FC<{X:Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>,Y:string}> = ({X,Y}) => {

console.log(Y)

   return (
      <Fragment>

         <input type={'text'}
            size={50}
            maxLength={150}
            placeholder={'Search for anything'}
            alt={'search'}
            spellCheck={false}
            autoComplete={'off'}
            value={Y}
            onChange={({ target }) => {X(target.value);}} />
         <input type={'submit'} value={'search'} />

      </Fragment>
   )

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply type the method to take a string and return void like

```
type Props = {
   X: (val: string) => void,
   Y: string
}
```

and use it like

```
const SearchText = ({X,Y}: Props) => {
```

Comment: @EdgarYedigaryan, let me know if the above solution works for you